# Clojure: precise definition of reducer

Tags: clojure, reducers

The [Clojure website](http://clojure.org/reference/reducers) defines a **reducer** as follows:

> A reducer is the combination of a reducible collection (a collection that knows how to reduce itself) with a reducing function (the "recipe" for what needs to be done during the reduction).

The following is the implementation of the `reducer` function (from Rich's [blog post on the topic](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/15/anatomy-of-reducer.html))

```
(defn reducer
   ([coll xf]
    (reify
     clojure.core.protocols/CollReduce
     (coll-reduce [_ f1 init]
       (clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce coll (xf f1) init)))))
```

It seems that it would be more accurate to say that a reducer is a combination of a reducible collection and a **reducing function transformer** (later called a [transducer](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2014/8/6/transducers-are-coming)), instead of a **reducing function**.

The reducer does not "know" anything about the reducing function, which is provided by `reduce`. All it knows is a "recipe" for taking some reducing function and modifying (transforming) it.

Is my understanding the right defintion of "reducer"? Or is there something I'm missing about the "reducible collection with a reducing function" definition?

Answer (score 0):

The language in the docs is confusing a reducer and a transducer. A transducer can be thought of as nothing more than an optimized implementation of a reducer, with the goal of reducing object allocation (& subsequent GC). This optimization does not change the conceptual model of a reducer.

So, sticking to plain-old `reduce`, it's goal is to simply to provide a way to *accumulate* a result from a sequence. The simplest example is to total a sequence:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str] )
  (:use tupelo.core)) ; it->

(def values (range 6))
(spyx values)

(def total (reduce + 0 values))
(spyx total)

;=> values => (0 1 2 3 4 5)
;=> total => 15
```

However, the "reducing function" can do anything. It can also return a sequence, not just a scalar value:

```
(def duplicate (reduce (fn [cum-result new-val]         ; accumulating function
                        (conj cum-result new-val))
                      []                                ; initial value
                      values))                          ; sequence to process
(spyx duplicate)
;=> duplicate => [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Here is a more complicated reducing function that computes the integral of the input sequence:

```
(def integral (reduce (fn [cum-state new-val]             ; accumulating function
                        (let [integ-val (+ (:running-total cum-state)  new-val) ]
                          { :integ-vals     (conj (:integ-vals cum-state) integ-val)
                            :running-total  integ-val} ))
                      {:integ-vals [] :running-total 0}   ; initial value
                      values))                            ; sequence to process
(spyx integral)
;=> integral => {:integ-vals [0 1 3 6 10 15], :running-total 15}
```

So this is the big difference compared to `map`.  We call `map` as:

```
(def y (map f x))
```

where `x` and `y` are sequences, and the result looks like

```
y(0) = f( x(0) )   ; math notation used here
y(1) = f( x(1) )
y(2) = f( x(2) )
...
```

So each y(i) depends *only* on the function `f` and x(i).  In contrast, we define `reduce` as:

(def y (reduce f init x))

where `x` and `y` are sequences, and `init` is a scalar (like `0` or `[]`). The result looks like

```
y(0) = f( init, x(0) )   ; math notation used here
y(1) = f( y(0), x(1) )
y(2) = f( y(1), x(2) )
...
```

So the *reducing function* `f`is a function of *2 values*: the cumulative result and the new `x` value.

Comment: "A transducer can be thought of as nothing more than an optimized implementation of a reducer"...huh? A transducer is supposed to "transform" a reducer into another reducer. It is a mapping from the space of reducers to the space of reducers. It is not itself a reducer.

Comment: "Transducers compose directly, without awareness of input or creation of intermediate aggregates."  Not creating the intermediate sequences is the benefit here, so there is less memory churn compared to applying several sequence operations (map, filter, reduce...) one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the source of the `reducer` function from the blog:

```
(defn reducer
  ([coll xf]
   (reify
    clojure.core.protocols/CollReduce
    (coll-reduce [_ f1 init]
      (clojure.core.protocols/coll-reduce coll (xf f1) init)))))
```

you can see that the reducer asks the collection to reduce itself (by calling `coll-reduce` on the coll) and supplying a reducing function which is produced by calling the reducing function transformer (`(xf f1)`).

So I would say that the sentence:

> A reducer is a combination of **a reducible collection** and **a reducing function transformer** (later called a transducer), instead of a reducing function.

is more accurate as what you need to start with is **a reducible collection** and **a reducing function transformer**. A reduction function is just a result of calling the reducing function transformer.